# Is random forest applied only to continuous response variable?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to apply random forest on a binary response variable, but it's saying the response variable has 5 or fewer unique values. Was it happening because random forest works only with the continuous response variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Random forests are applied to discrete response variables as well. What software are you using? If it is the `randomForest` package in R then you should convert your responses to factors using the `factor()` function.